# T-Sql statement to perform inserts or updates comparing data in Master and data in two tables joined

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How do I write a SQL statement that will Insert millions and Update millions of records in a Sql Server using T-SQL? While inserting the records the SQL should be able to create the primary key using a criteria. Example : Table 1 and Table 2 are joined by a unique key. And this data from these tables are compared against a master table using another unique key between Table 1 and the master table. Iterating through the Master table if data exists in Table 1 then the necessary Update records in Table 3 is performed, or if data does not exist in Table 2, then inserting the record which is in the master into Table 1 and Table 2. The Key unfortunately is a varchar(10) in this format : 0002558201. So that is why we need to get the last key using a MAX and then reformat with the left '000' s. The table also has orphan keys beginning with RF.... which should ignored when getting the latest primary key in the table, and incrementing the Primary Keys in both Table 1 and Table 2. The Primary Key in Table 2 is a signed integer. As the client does not want to consider deleting those records.   Also the foreign key here is what we use to join the Master table to this table.

Sample Data for table1:

PKey_Id      FName    LName   Foreign_Key_Master
0002558201  Richard  Smith    15494934

Sample Data for table2:

PKey_SNo   Foreign_Key_Table1     Cost       Calls
1           0002558201            123000      50000

Sample Data for Master:

PKey_QNo    FirstName   LastName  HCost  SalCalls
15494934    Richard     Smith     765    8766
15494935    John        Doe       743    8342

Comment: I quite honestly do not understand what on earth you're trying to do.... can you explain better? Can you show us the table structures and maybe gives you an example of the data in those various tables, and how it relates??

Comment: Table 1 has a primary Key : SNo and Table 2 has a foreign Key Sno. So the join is Table1.SNo = Table2.SNo. Table 1 has another Key : P_Id. The master table has unique key : ProvId. Hence Table 1 and Master table are related by Table1.P_id = Master.ProvId.

Comment: Can you give us a sample data that each table might contain?

Comment: First fix your database. The structure you describe is dangerous at best (what happens when you have race conditions) and certainly is ineffective if you want to insert millions of rows any way other than one at a time.

Comment: I certainly have suggested it to the client to fix the database long ago. But the task of fixing the database is another issue. I would appreciate a solution for the issue above with the T-SQL. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately SQL Server 2005 does not support a `MERGE` statement. The best you can do is a two-step process for each table you'd like.

Do the update something like this:

```
 UPDATE Table3
    SET ...
   FROM Table2
        JOIN Table3
          ON Table2.key = Table3.key;

 INSERT Table3
 SELECT ...
   FROM Table2
        LEFT JOIN Table3
          ON Table2.key = Table3.key
  WHERE Table3.key IS NULL;
```

The `WHERE` clause in the last statement will ensure that only records that don't match the key will be inserted.

Comment: Set Key = Key + 1;     Any idea how I can add an incrementing key like this into the Insert indicated above...... Insert Table3 Select (Key + 1), ..... I need to save the pervious key value like this     Key = Key + 1;     Set KeyTemp = Key;     Set Key = KeyTemp; as I need to use this to insert the other record and so on.....How will I do this process in the Insert Table3 Select .....From Table2.... thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ruruboy, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923950/is-is-possible-to-get-new-values-for-id-identity-before-inserting-data-in-a-tab/3930163#3930163