# Get Identity Attribute value before inserting in Database

Tags: c#, .net, database

I have a table and it has one of the attribute set as identity. I want to get the value of the identity attribute that would be generated after I enter a value to the database.

I have EmpTable made of EmpID and EmpName. EmpID is set as Identity. I want to fetch the EmpID value before inserting a new row to the database.

Comment: Which database do you use? For SQLServer there is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923950/is-is-possible-to-get-new-values-for-id-identity-before-inserting-data-in-a-ta?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against trying to do this with a table that is set up to use an integer column as the primary key.  You will run into concurrency problems if you simply fetch the previous ID and increment it. Instead you should use a GUID (uniqueidentifier in SQL) as your primary key.

This will allow you to generate a new GUID in your code that can safely be saved to the database at a later stage.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sure the server knows where the auto-increment count is in its sequence, but there is almost nothing useful you can do with that information.  Imagine you go to the Post Office and they hand out numbered tickets so they can serve customers in order.  Of course you could ask them what the next number they'll give out is, but since anyone can walk in at any time you don't know you'll get that number.  If you don't know that you'll get it, you can't do anything with it - e.g. writing it as a reference number on a form would be a mistake.

Depending on what you're trying to do, your two main options are:

1. Use a client-generated guid as your identifier.  This kind of messes up the order so the analogy isn't great, but imagine if each customer who walked in could generate a random number that they are sure would never have been used before.  They could use that to fill out forms before taking a number.
2. Take a number, but do it in a transaction with the other operations.  A customer can take a number and use it to fill out some paperwork.  If they realize they left their money at home, they just throw everything away and you never call their number.

Why do you think you need this information?  Can you use either of these strategies instead?